# Why do so many people on CR have a reputation score of 101?

Tags: discussion, reputation, stackexchange, users

I was looking through the user list and it looks like a lot of people registered on Code Review (the main site, not meta) already have a reputation score of 101 without having participated on this site whatsoever. Is this a residual score calculated from their participation on other Stack Exchange sites?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Correct -- you get +100 bonus reputation on any new site in [the Stack Exchange network](http://stackexchange.com/sites), so long as you have +200 rep somewhere in the network.

Since you start with 1 rep, that means you end up with +101 rep total.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. This is my first time on a SE site (if you don't count Stack Overflow). I'm relatively new there, too.

Comment: Welcome to the club :-)